# distinct/join two table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

shops table:

```
   +--+-------+--------+
    |id|name   |date    |
    +--+-------+--------+
    |1 |x      |March 10|
    +--+-------+--------+
    |2 |y      |March 10|
    +--+-------+--------+
```

category table :

```
+--+-------+
|id|title  |
+--+-------+
|1 |tools  |
+--+-------+
|2 |foods  |
+--+-------+
```

shop categories table (shop_cats):

```
+--+-------+--------+
|id|shop_id|cat_id  |
+--+-------+--------+
|1 |1      |1       |
+--+-------+--------+
|2 |1      |2       |
+--+-------+--------+
```

i want to get shops by category  (categories are stored in the $cat array)

```
     $this->db->select('shops.*');
     $this->db->from('shops');
     if(!empty($cat))
     {
         $this->db->join('shop_cats' , 'shop_cats.shop_id = shops.id' );
         $this->db->where_in('shop_cats.cat_id' , $cat);
     }


    $this->db->limit($limit , $offset);
    $res = $this->db->get();
```

my problem is it returns duplicate results 
for example in this table

```
+--+-------+--------+
|id|shop_id|cat_id  |
+--+-------+--------+
|1 |1      |1       |
+--+-------+--------+
|2 |1      |2       |
+--+-------+--------+
```

if i want shops with (1,2) category i get shop with id = 1 , twice .
i want it to return each shop only once without any duplicate .

i've tried to use group by

```
 if(!empty($cat))
         {
             $this->db->join('shop_cats' , 'shop_cats.shop_id = shops.id' );
             $this->db->group_by('shop_cats.shop_id');
             $this->db->where_in('shop_cats.cat_id' , $cat);
         }
```

it didn't work , i've also tried

```
 if(!empty($cat))
       {         $this->db->select('DISTINCT shop_cats.shop_id');
             $this->db->join('shop_cats' , 'shop_cats.shop_id = shops.id' );
             $this->db->where_in('shop_cats.cat_id' , $cat);
         }
```

but i get syntax error !

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im i want it to return each shop only once , right now it will join cat_shop table to shops and it doesn't care if  it's already been joined or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$this->db->distinct('shops.*');
$this->db->from('shops');
$this->db->join('shop_cats', 'shop_cats.shop_id = shops.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('shop_cats.cat_id', $cat);
$this->db->limit($limit , $offset);
$res = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: thanx it doesn't work , distinc doesn't even show in the query when i print out last query

Comment: @max I have tested the query and works fine. Maybe your error is somewhere else in your code. Also it is not distinc it is distinct. Do you have that correctly in your code?